# Update offsetTop and height of an element using refs when orientation changes in react

Tags: reactjs, orientation, parallax

I'm building a website using react and I'm using the **offsetTop** propriety and the **clientHeight** propriety to implement a custom parallax effect (I save them in a local state to use them for computation). To obtain these values I created a ref that I've inserted in my component.

When the screen size changes these values should be re-assessed and the state updated because, otherwise, the parallax effect doesn't show properly. To perform this operation I simply update the state with the method below. It works well when the screen gets resized, however, it gives me a lot of problems when the orientation change (I obtain wrong values for height and offset).

```
handleResizeOrOrientationChange() {
    let node = this.sectionRef.current;
    if (node) {
        this.setState({
            height: node.clientHeight,
            topOffset: node.offsetTop
        }, () => console.log(this.state));
    }
}
```

[Notice: the "if" is always executed]

Answer (score 0):

After a series of trials, I found a possible solution to the problem: during the orientation changes refs don't behave properly in terms of computing sizes, and even postponing the rendering in "componentDidUpdate()" isn't working since it's triggered too early to be effective. However, since the sizes are needed during scrolling for an effective rendering, I changed my approach by checking the height of a component every time I scroll the page. In this way every time there's a resizing and/or an orientation change it's detected at the exact moment I scroll the page.

This will deal well with resizing. However, with an orientation change, the UI can look bad until the user scrolls the page. To solve the problem I force the page to scroll to the top every time there's an orientation change.

Even if this approach works, it's still a workaround.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for this?

Comment: Unluckily I didn't work on the project anymore. @olefrank